# Implement unique occurrence against each other

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am trying to develop a card game, in which I have a situation like I need to present cards against each other in such a way so that they have never played with each other. So in general, I will have two different stack of cards, and they will be presented with each other. So it could be like

```
 A  B  C  D 
 H  U  O  P
```

Any one of the card will be swiped away from infront of any letter, say user remove H from infront of A, the U will be presented to A, then U swiped away O will be presented.

In above scenario H, U, and O have played with A, so in future they should never play with A.

How to implement this.

Any light, anything that can help me, would be highly appreciated.

**See image for better explanation**
   [image]

Thanks.

Comment: This may be more appropriate on puzzling.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Shailesh Thanks for the suggestion, I will put there.